# Alert if input is empty

Tags: jquery, perl

I have a form that I would like all fields to be filled in. If a field is not filled out, I would like to display a red background of the field and an message.

```
    \$('#id_form').blur(function()
    {
        if( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
            $(this).parents('p').addClass('warning');
        }

print $q->start_form (-method => 'post', -action => "add.pl", -id => 'id_form');
print $q->legend({-class => "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"},"");
print $q->input ({-id => 'name', -name => 'name',-type => 'text' , -size => 20, -style => ' margin-left:300 px' },"<br>");
```

I am not sure this is the right way!

Comment: what happens with this code ?

Comment: doesn't work. it is the same as if it i dont put it

Comment: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/12/jquery-to-check-all-textboxes-empty.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your element to the DOM. You can use the `$(document).ready()`, or use jQuery's anonymous function like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#id_form').blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('p').addClass('warning');
        };
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/tYhpw/

```
$('#id_form input').on('blur', function () {
    if( $(this).val() == '' ) {
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #f00');
    }else{
        $(this).css('border','1px solid #000');
    }
});
```

Comment: doen't work i can't understand why

Comment: can you write your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and share link to help us understand what's going on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eZuBU/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/tYhpw/

Answer (score 0):

I used this Jquery function with a button to check if all fields had been filled in:

```
    function check(){

    var ok = 1;

    $('input').each(function(){

    if($(this).val().length == 0){ 
        ok = 0; $(this).css('background-color','red');
        alert("Error message"); 
    }

    else{ $(this).css('background-color',''); }
});

if(ok != 1){ alert("Error message"); }

else{ $('#form').submit(); }

}
```

Maybe this helps?